# Need to Emulate this style of Flash Carousel

Tags: jquery, xml, flash

Hey I need to emulate the Carousel at this site:

[EMC Website](http://www.emc.com/)

Is there any tutorials or already built free frameworks that can do this type of thing? The big need is to be able to have this database driven(or XML) and be able to have embedded links (like that site does) so that when they click on those links I can send the user to their respective pages.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not all languages display the carousel.
It is a 2D one

You have free tutorials and sample files [here](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/).

Scroll down and check out:

- Creating 3D Carousels: Part 1 Learn
  how to create slick looking 3D
  carousels using Actionscript.
- Creating 3D Carousels: Part 2 In part
  2 we dynamically create carousel
  items using XML and show tooltips.
- Creating 3D Carousels: Part 3 In part
  3 we animate our carousel and create
  a mini, interactive Flash site